# How to combine empty cells when loading data via SQL loader and displaying on JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

```css
h1{
                    text-align: center;
                    color: #ff4d4d;
                    font-size: 70px;
                  }
                

                table {
        
   border-color: black;
   border-width: 5px;
                overflow: hidden;
                border-collapse:collapse;
                width: 100%
                
                }
                
                
  th {
   
                        border-color: black;
   font-family: monospace;
                        position: relative;
                        background-color: #ff4d4d;
                        color: #ffffff;
                        background-clip: padding-box;
                       
                        
                        
  }
                td{
                    border-bottom: none;
                }
                td #noborder {
                    border-bottom: none;
                }
            
/*                tr:hover {
                            background-color: #ffcccc;
                          
                          }

                          td{
                            position: relative;
                            border-bottom: none;
                          }
                          td:hover::after,
                          th:hover::after {
                            content: "";
                            position: absolute;
                            background-color: #ffcccc;
                            left: 0;
                            top: -5000px;
                            height: 10000px;
                            width: 100%;
                            z-index: -1;
                          }*/
                          .dropbtn {
                            background-color: #4CAF50;
                            color: white;
                            padding: 16px;
                            font-size: 16px;
                            border: none;
                          }

                          .dropdown {
                            position: relative;
                            display: inline-block;
                          }

                          .dropdown-content {
                            display: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            background-color: #f1f1f1;
                            min-width: 160px;
                            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                            z-index: 1;
                          }

                          .dropdown-content a {
                            color: black;
                            padding: 12px 16px;
                            text-decoration: none;
                            display: block;
                          }
                          
                          td:empty{
                              border-bottom: none;
                              border-top: none;
                          }
                          
                          .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

                          .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

                          .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
html>
<head>
<h1> f1 </h1>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>OSCSUI</title>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>


    
</head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>

<body>

</body>
<form method="post">

<table id="table1" border ='1' cellpadding="10">
<tr>
<th>T1</th>
<th>T2</th>
<th>T3</th>
<th>T4</th>
<th>T5</th>
<th>T6</th>
<th>T7</th>
<th>T8</th>
<th>T9</th>
<th>T10</th>
<th>T11</th>
<th>T12</th>
<th>T13</th>
<th>T14</th>
<th>T15</th>
    </tr>
<%
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("");
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE ");

while(rs.next())
{
%>
    <tr><td><%=rs.getString("T1") == null ? "" : rs.getString("T1") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T2") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T2")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T3") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T3")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T4") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T4")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T5") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T5")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T6")== null ? "" : rs.getString("T6")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T7")== null ? "" :rs.getString("T7") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T8") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T8")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T9")== null ? "" :rs.getString("T9") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T10") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T10")%></td>
        <td id="noborder"><%=rs.getString("T10")== null ? "" :rs.getString("T10") %></td>  
        <td><%=rs.getString("T12")== null ? "" :rs.getString("T12") %></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T13") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T13")%></td>
        <td><%=rs.getString("T14") == null ? "" :rs.getString("T14")%></td>
        
        <td>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <button class="dropbtn">T15</button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">TASK 1</a>
                    <a href="#">TASK 2</a>
                  
                  </div></div>  </td>
        
               
    </tr>
        <%

}
%>
    </table>
    <%
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    }
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    }




%>

 

</form>

</html>
```

I have my data in a `.CSV` file. I loaded it into the data base using SQL Loader and now the Output on the `JSP` page has empty cells too. What I want to do is basically merge the empty cells and display it as a single column, However I am unable to do it, since its not fixed and I have to merge different number of rows in each column.

I have tried the `CSS` properties of `td:empty`, However it does not do the trick since I said the data is different each time, so I am looking for something which will merge the rows accordingly. Please suggest what I should do.

edit:  I have attached my code, the point is basically I have to combine different number of rows per column and that is not fixed as  I am pulling data from the CSV so that keeps changing.

Comment: You should provide some code of what you already have tried. Anway I suggest you should take a look at colspan.

Comment: Just uploaded the code, I have tried colspan, however I am pretty unsure of what I should set it to, since the number keeps changing with the data.! So in a CSV File, I have one row in first column, two in second, third , fourth .... sixth, then 4 in seventh and I want all these in one single row. 
I am not sure if I am making myself clear enough,

Comment: Read your data for the complete row first. Figure out how many successive columns are empty. And then do your presentation of it.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry, Could you please elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code you have 15 elements per row in the database.

So you need to read all those columns into a single data structure, for example a string array of length 15.

After this iterate over the data structure:
If your column is not empty put it's presentation into the jsp.

Else continue iterating till you reach the next non-empty element or the end of the row. Don't forget to count the empty ones.

If you reach the end or find the next one, output the (empty) column with the proper colspan, reset the counter value and continue with the processing.